# resolving values after promise has resolved

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have a code like this.. I want to fetch some contents and after all have loaded, do something. 
So I use Promise.all and access resolved values later. but it is giving values but like Promise {' content here'}. (See console.log..)
I was gonna use Regex to extract it but then i check its type which isnt string but object with no keys? Why?

```
      var request=require('request');

      var urls=['someurl','someurl2','someurl3'];
      var contents=[];

      urls.forEach(function (u) {
      contents.push(getContent(u) );
      });

      Promise.all(contents)
      .then(function () {
        // All should be loaded by now?

       // Promises which are resolved are fulfiled, and values can be accessed later right?
       contents.forEach(function (promise) {
       var content = Promise.resolve(promise);
        console.log(content); // Promise {'test'} ??
        console.log(typeof content,Object.keys(content));
        // object [] ???
      });

      }).
      catch(function(err) {
       //handle error here

      });



      function getContent(url) {
       return new Promise ( function (resolve,reject) {
        /** commented and stripped out for testing
        request(url, function (err,response, data) {
         if(err) {
          reject(Error(err));
         }

       }); **/
       resolve("test");
       });
       }
```

Answer (score 4):

`contents` still only holds promises.
You can never directly extract the value of a promise; you can only consume it from a `then()` callback.

Instead, `Promise.all()` return a promise *for the array of results*.

Change your `then()` call to take that array as a callback parameter and use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're accessing the results in the wrong way:

```
Promise.all(contents).then( function(data) {
    // data holds an array with the return values of the promises
    console.log(data);
});
```

Second thing: you're not creating a Promise correctly, essentially, you're never resolving them in your `getContent()` function, so you'll never get the data you want!

```
function getContent(url) {
       return new Promise ( function (resolve,reject) {
        request(url, function (err,response, data) {
         if(err) {
            // reject the promise in case of error
            reject(Error(err));
         } else {
            // resolve the promise with the output you need
            resolve(data);
         }
});
```

When you call `resolve()`, the promise gets resolved and the input you give it is passed on. 
When all promises you specified in `Promise.all()` are resolved, the callback will be executed and you'll be able to access the data returned with `resolve()`.